# Почему fail2ban не банит?

Tags: freebsd

Создал `jail` - в статусе все хорошо :

```
Status for the jail: new-jail
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  |- Total failed: 10
|  `- File list:    /var/log/new-jail-acces.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned: 2
   `- Banned IP list:   176.9.136.47
```

В `/usr/local/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` :

```
[new-jail]
enabled = true
filter = new-jail
port = https
logpath = /var/log/new-jail-acces.log
ignoreip = 192.168.1.1
maxretry = 2
bantime = 86400
findtime = 600
action = bsd-ipfw
```

В `/usr/local/etc/fail2ban/action.d/bsd-ipfw.conf` :

```
actionban = e=`ipfw table <table> add <ip> 2>&1`; x=$?; [ $x -eq 0 -o "$e" = 'ipfw: setsockopt(IP_FW_TABLE_XADD): File exists' ] || { echo "$e" 1>&2; exit $x; }
```